# A better way to write this mysql select query

Tags: mysql

I have a long query that is zapping resources and need to rewrite it.
The obvious problem with it is the use of "not in" in the where clause.
My initial thought is to rewrite it doing away with all of the self joins and doing a "not exists" on a subquery. Any thoughts on doing that, or a maybe a more efficient idea than that one?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT a.referenceid,
       a.memberid AS d1,
       b.memberid AS d2,
       c.memberid AS d3,
       d.memberid AS d4,
       e.memberid AS d5,
       f.memberid AS d6
FROM   jos_comprofiler_members AS a FORCE INDEX (aprm)
       LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler_members AS b FORCE INDEX (aprm)
              ON a.memberid = b.referenceid
                 AND b.accepted = 1
                 AND b.pending = 0
       LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler_members AS c FORCE INDEX (aprm)
              ON b.memberid = c.referenceid
                 AND c.accepted = 1
                 AND c.pending = 0
       LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler_members AS d FORCE INDEX (pamr)
              ON c.memberid = d.referenceid
                 AND d.accepted = 1
                 AND d.pending = 0
       LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler_members AS e FORCE INDEX (pamr)
              ON d.memberid = e.referenceid
                 AND e.accepted = 1
                 AND e.pending = 0
       LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler_members AS f FORCE INDEX (pamr)
              ON e.memberid = f.referenceid
                 AND f.accepted = 1
                 AND f.pending = 0
WHERE  a.referenceid = 1593
       AND a.accepted = 1
       AND a.pending = 0
       AND f.memberid = 1593
       AND b.memberid NOT IN ( 1593, a.memberid )
       AND c.memberid NOT IN ( 1593, a.memberid, b.memberid )
       AND d.memberid NOT IN ( 1593, a.memberid, b.memberid, c.memberid )
       AND e.memberid NOT IN (
           1593, a.memberid, b.memberid, c.memberid, d.memberid )
       AND f.memberid NOT IN ( 1593, a.memberid, b.memberid, c.memberid,
                               d.memberid, e.memberid )
LIMIT  0, 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear about what is the point of these joins..

Comment: You are trying to get 6 memberIDs from the same table that are not the same? Could you provide more info about the goal of this query?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a bit much to me too.
The basic story here is someone else wrote this code and now I need to optimize it so it doesn't kill our resources. I really don't know what the point of writing this with all of the left joins was, and the "not in" in the where statement puts it over the top. This table is basically to store what members are connected to who. My thought was to do away with the joins and just do a "not exists(" on a subquery, my question is am I still too inefficient doing that, and if so is a better way to maybe use an outter join or something instead?

Comment: To clarify, each time a connection is made two rows are added to the table. Basically a mirror image each other with the memberid and referenceid reversed, the person being asked to connect then has to accept or deny the request. This query here is basically just to check if someone is connected and if the connection is approved. It's way more complicated than it needs to be as it is in in its current form. I just don't want to spend the time rewriting it and not be as efficient as I can, hence reaching out to you guys on opinions. I honestly d/k what the joins are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is looking for all members within a distance 6 of 1593.  Rhetorical question:  Is this related to six degrees of separation?

Normally, finding such lists in SQL requires recursive queries or some non-SELECT construct (loops, cursors).  I am not sure how MySQL handles the `not in`, when the list consists of variable members.  However, I suspect that it is doing some sort of nested loop join for each one.

Suggestion:  move the `not in` statements to the `on` clause.  For example:

```
   LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler_members AS c FORCE INDEX (aprm)
          ON b.memberid = c.referenceid
             AND c.accepted = 1
             AND c.pending = 0
             AND (c.memberId <> b.MemberId an c.MemberId <> a.MemberId and c.MemberId <> 1593)
```

This could improve things.  Or make them worse.  But it is an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gordon, I was able to finally track down exactly where the query was being created and you're correct, it was to determine the separation degree between the member viewing the profile and the profile owner. We don't need that functionality so for the time being I simply commented the query out of the function. If for some reason that functionality is needed again it'll have to be rewritten but for now out of sight out of mind lol. I still can't help but wonder though how the best and most efficient way to rewrite that would be.

Comment: @SpencerFraise . . . If you are only looking for one member, then the best way might be to load that member into a temporary table, and then, in a while loop, iteratively add members in, one degree of separation at a time.